# ARCore project has no gradle file in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore

I downloaded ARCore project and edited the project to run on older devices than Android 7.0 by following some online tutorial that simply editing the manifest file minsdkversion. Then I decompiled the code and signed it with my own debug keys. But all I see is a project without gradle and I am confused with everything at this point.Here is a screenshot of my whole project and gradle settings.

[image]

[image]

And when I try to run the project, I get this.
[image]

So my question is, where is Gradle file? Has anyone tried it and run into this kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Do know for grale, but the error you get is the TestRunner, that runs the unit tests, this is not the main application launcher.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help, but this doesn't answer the question